# how to show animated wait window, while database related working is going on

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, async-await

I am working on C# 4.0 WinForm application, these is actually accounting related application, main function is to save data in database and retrieve it from.

back end using SqlServer 2008 r2 Express.

The problem is when we perform command on database it takes time of few seconds, at that time my applications main window becomes halted.

when i performs command on database execution returns on main application when whole command is executed on database.

Just Like "NonQuery()"

so, i am showing a form before it and closing that form after the command, but problem is i am putting a GIF image on the form, because exection is halted on main application, the gif don't shows animation until the command is executed.

so that i putted it on a BackGroundWorker, but main thread is halted so its child tread also become halt.

we can not put database transaction in background worker, becuase sometime working is depended on result retrieved from database, and we want to halt application untill data is not fetched, but in this case also we want that on wait form, the gif image should show its animation.

What to do in this case, and how to do.

Comment: please describe the reason for minus voting.

Answer (score 2):

Use `BackgroundWorker` for SQL taransiction, but put `Form.Enabled=False` before starting `BackgroundWorker` and then `Form.Enabled=true` on `RunWorkerCompleted` event of BackgroundWorker.

This will free a main thread for showing animation of .gif picture, and stop user to continue working before all data queries are ready.

Or if `.Enabled=false` looking ugly for you, you can create a method which activate/disable all main buttons/controls and stop user to do things...

Or open other form(with your animated .gif) with `.ShowDialog()` method. And then from this form start a `BackgroundWorker` and prevent user to close this "second" form before SQl transictions are ready...

Answer (score 1):

You could run your method in a new thred:

```
  Thread query = new Thread(() => Method("Method", "Parameters", Blah));
  query.Start();
  //start your animation

  while (query.IsAlive)
  {
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(10);
  }

  //end your animation
```

This will free up the UI thread for your animation and requires minimal modification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand why you can't use a Backgroundworker...

You can try to use the keywords async and await for your database stuff, so that the form is not freezing. You can take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/hh156513.aspx)

Comment: i want to halt whole application when working on database, but only wait form should be free, and gif image can show its animation.

Comment: Why don't you look your application just be disabling all controls except the gif-image?

Comment: disabling controls and enabling them, takes more effort, time and cpu resources, and we saw some controls behave UN-expected, after enable them from disable state.

Comment: Just put your controls into a panel (or something else) and disable this at once. After you set panel.Enabled = false. Call panel.Refresh().

Answer (score 0):

That functionality called loader...  Which shows while loading page takes time...

"
  
     
           
                     
               
                                 
                                                                                
               **Loading...**

"

---

```
 <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateProgress1" runat="server">
 <ProgressTemplate>
       <div id="progressBackgroundFilter">
                 </div>
           <div id="processMessage" style="text-align: center">
                             <asp:Image ID="imgLoader" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/loader.gif" />
                                                                            <br />
           <b>Loading...</b>
           </div>
</ProgressTemplate>
```

Comment: i know about progress bar, in the given example sleep command would execute 100 time and each time after execute it execution returns to main application, in my case i doesn't have execution in main application until the whole command is executed.